# OpenCV Hough Circle Transform Not Working

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, shapes, detection

I have followed OpenCV's tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html#additional-resources) for circle detection on my Raspberry Pi. This is the code that I am using which is the same as the tutorial except a different image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('watch.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                       param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('image',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Then when I ran the script this is what I was presented with this
[image]

and this is the original image

[image]

What is causing this to happen?

Thank You in Advance!

Edit:

[image]

Comment: The error in the edit means that no circles were found in the image. This question explains it better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648387/opencv-hough-circle-transform-needs-8-bit-image/38660785#38660785

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The large amount of circles generated by *Hough Circle Transform* is caused by the low value of the threshold for center detection, which is `param2` in `cv2.HoughCircles` in your case.

So try to increase the value of `param2` to avoid false detections.

Also you can adjust `minRadius` and `maxRadius` values for better results.

**EDIT:**

I have just tried example from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) and changed only `param2` to `10`, `minRadius` to `30` and `maxRadius` to `50`. The result is good enough:

[image]

The example from the link above is written with *C++*, but you can compare parameters and the sequence of functions invocations to refine your own algorithm.

Comment: Is it possible to use Hough Circle Transform with a live feed of video?

Comment: @Loanb222 yes, of course it's possible. But the performance is a big deal.

Comment: I keep on getting an error when I use it with the pi camera. I updated my question with the picture of the error

Comment: @Loanb222 Unfortunately I'm not so good at python. Possibly it's better for you to create a separate question for this issue...

Comment: @Loanb222 First of all you can improve your algorithm on a single image and only after that test it with video.